# golang, run with daemonize

Tags: go, daemon

After build to file. I run it by daemonize with command

```
daemonize /var/www/repo/bin/tracking_api 1>> /var/www/repo/bin/tracking_api.log
```

I see it generate a new file but nothing in that file. In code I log.Print a lot.

I just know basic about GO, please guide me to log that. Is there any easier way to run golang to server instead of using daemonize?

Answer (score 0):

Go logger logs to standard error, redirect standard error and it will work fine.

```
/var/www/repo/bin/tracking_api 2>&1 >> /var/www/repo/bin/tracking_api.log
```

Unfortunately, `daemonize` tool closes standard input, output and error so the only solution is to change the log file with [SetOutput](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#SetOutput) function.

Comment: Well, look here http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/ the tool closes standard streams.

Answer (score 0):

`nohup /var/www/repo/bin/tracking_api > /var/www/repo/bin/tracking_api.log &`

Comment: You can improve "code/command"-only answers by explaining what your solution does or what the topic creator did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [immortal](https://immortal.run) basically is a supervisor, you can either use it like this:

```
immortal -l /var/www/repo/bin/tracking_api.log tracking_api
```

or by a [configuration YAML](https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/) file which gives you more options, for example:

```
cmd: tracking_api
log:
    file: /var/www/repo/bin/tracking_api.log
    age: 86400 # seconds
    num: 7     # int
    size: 1    # MegaBytes
    timestamp: true # will add timesamp to log
```

If you would like to keep also the standard error output in a separate file you could use something like:

```
cmd: tracking_api
log:
    file: /var/www/repo/bin/tracking_api.log
    age: 86400 # seconds
    num: 7     # int
    size: 1    # MegaBytes
stderr:
    file: /var/www/repo/bin/tracking_api.log
    age: 86400 # seconds
    num: 7     # int
    size: 1    # MegaBytes
    timestamp: true # will add timesamp to log
```